# A few basics with AND or OR I need some help with

Tags: bash

I have a few problems that I seem to be stumped with. It seems to be with the logic of Bash.

```
if [ "$argument" = "Y" -o "$argument" = "YES" ];
  then
  …
fi
```

Is there a way to create this statement without using `"$argument"` twice? and how could I expand this to add maybe 3 or 4 answers e.g. Yup, OK

Secondly,

```
while [ "$argument" != "Y" ] || [ "$argument" != "YES" ] || [ "$argument" != "N" ] || [ "$argument" != "NO" ]; do
   echo "Not a valid selection"
done
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but no matter the entered statement into `$argument`, I always get `Not a valid selection` it won't accept Y, YES, N, or NO

Comment: This is where understanding formal logic can be very helpful. For instance, you can apply one of De Morgan's laws here: `(a != b OR a != c)` is equivalent to `NOT (a = b AND a = c)`, which might make the problem more obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example where it's always saying the answer is invalid, that's because the logic you've written has no valid truthful cases.  No matter what the value of `$argument` is, it will *always* not be equal to either `Y` or `YES`, as if it is one of these values, it *cannot* be the other.

You might want to look into a `case` statement:

```
valid=0
while [[ valid -eq 0 ]]; do
    read -p 'Really? > ' argument
    case "$argument" in
        Y*|y*)
            valid=1
            : handle 'yes' cases
            ;;
        N*|n*)
            valid=1
            : handle 'no' cases
            ;;
        *)
            printf 'Invalid input "%s".  Please say "yes" or "no".\n' "$argument" 1>&2
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Bear in mind, you can also eschew the wildcards and use e. g. `YES|yes|Y|y` for the test cases so that a response of `You know what? On second thought, I'll pass` being parsed as a "yes".

Comment: Thanks that helps quite a lot, the information will help me build out further

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> if [ "$argument" = "Y" -o "$argument" = "YES" ]; then
> ```
>
> Is there a way to create this statement without using "$argument" twice?

In standard shell, with `case`:

```
case $argument in
    Y|YES) echo "it's 'Y' or 'YES'";;
    *) echo "it's something else";;
esac
```

In Bash/Ksh/Zsh, using regexes:

```
if [[ $argument =~ Y|YES ]]; then
    ...
```

In Bash/Ksh (or Zsh with `setopt kshglob`), using Ksh-style extended globs:

```
if [[ $argument = @(Y|YES) ]]; then
    ...
```

Of course, there's various other options, like the regex `^Y(ES)?$`, or `^[yY]` which matches anything starting with `y` or `Y` (including `yuck, no!`).

---

> ```
> while [ "$argument" != "Y" ] || [ "$argument" != "YES" ] ...
> ```
>
> I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here

In cases like this, it helps to work through the logic by hand. Let's say `argument` is `Y`, then `[ "$argument" != "Y" ]` is falsy, `[ "$argument" != "YES" ]` is truthy, so the result of the *or* is truthy. Repeat for other values, and you'll see at least one of the comparisons is always true.